# ionic app play local song on iphone from music library

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm making an ionic app, I want to add a song from the ios/android music library, is that possible? I can't seem to find any guide to do this, whenever I look up ionic audio player, it's all streaming from SoundCloud or some URL.

Comment: I think what you need is the [media from ionic native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/)

Comment: thanks, I've been reading through their docs, cant find how to choose a file from the phone's music.

Comment: You can use it in combination with the [file chooser plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/)

Comment: Filechooser plugin only supports Android